# handling community flagged video in youtube API, python

Tags: python, youtube-api

```
videos = get_channel_videos("UCqnbDFdCpuN8CMEg0VuEBqA") # this just get all the video from the "upload" playlist of each channel


vidList = []
for i in videos:
    vi = (i['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'])
    vidList.append(vi)
print(vidList); len(vidList)

captions = []
for id in vidList:
    sub = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript(id)
    captions.append(sub)
print(captions);len(captions)
```

I got the following error because the news video is flagged by community.

```
VideoUnavailable: 
Could not retrieve a transcript for the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vksEJR9EPQ8! 

This is most likely caused by:
The video is no longer available

If you are sure that the described cause is not responsible for this error and that a transcript should be retrievable, 
please create an issue at https://github.com/jdepoix/youtube-transcript-api/issues. 
Please add which version of youtube_transcript_api you are using and provide the information needed to replicate the error. 
Also make sure that there are no open issues which already describe your problem!
```

i tried append each videoID with &bpctr=9999999999 to get around the inappropriate video restriction. However, the function adds an "!" to the end of each url which mess it up.

Comment: Can't you just wrap this in a try/except block?

Comment: Would you made elaborate or link an example. I do need all the captions tho, i don't want to skip over them.

Comment: If they are not available, it does not seem like you have a choice. You will need to catch the error and skip over those videos.

Comment: The video actually is available: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vksEJR9EPQ8 they are just hidden behind this "i understand and wish to proceed" click, which adds an &bpctr=9999999999 to the url.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the API but does it have any function to check if the video is avaiable or not? If so, you could simply make an if statement that, in case the video is unavaiable, it would skip it